# Javascript order in array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to order an array. I tried following code:

```
var groupUserCounter=[];
groupUserCounter["g1"]=1;
groupUserCounter["g2"]=2;
groupUserCounter["g3"]=3;

console.log(groupUserCounter.sort(function(a, b){return b-a}));
```

It returned:

```
Array [  ]
```

How can I do descending order?

Comment: You've added some properties to your array object. Array Indices should be numbers.

Comment: What do you suggest? I can't remove properties

Comment: `groupUserCounter.push()` instead of assigning the properties.

Comment: I need key-value arrays. Push doesn't enough for me.

Comment: How is that? Those properties are not sortable. Please read how JS [arrays work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). If you need key-value pairs, you have to use an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). That's not sortable though.

Comment: Then use an object instead of an array. `var groupUserCounter = {};` But you'll have to write a sort function yourself then. Alternatively, push key/value pair objects into an array and do the sort with comparing those object properties.

Comment: What is this "g1" "g2" ??

Comment: @VivekGupta They are group codes. Key-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you're trying to mix arrays and objects in a way they don't work. Try pushing objects into an array like this:

```
var groupUserCounter = [];
groupUserCounter.push({'g1':1});
groupUserCounter.push({'g2':2});
groupUserCounter.push({'g3':3});
groupUserCounter.sort(function(a, b){
    var propA = Object.keys(a)[0],
        propB = Object.keys(b)[0];
    return b[propB] - a[propA];
});
```

Or just use an object altogether and write a sort function based around Object.keys(yourKeyValueObject) as RGraham kindly demonstrates below.

Comment: It pushes objects (key/value pair) to an array, so you can use the sort function of arrays. It then checks the first property of each object in the array and returns the difference between the value of the property in b and the property in a.